# R function for adding a column in a dataframe by using other three columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with many columns among which three (northcen, south, west) that I would merge in a new variable (location). For each variables, they are valued 1 if the observation is in that area, 0 if not (i.e. if one variable is valued 1, the other two variables are valued 0).
In the new variable "location" I would merge the three variable by putting in each row the labels "NC", "S", "W" when they are valued 1 or "E" if all the variables in a same row are valued 0.
The variable "location" should be a new variable (factor) of the initial datafarame.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dpylr` to add anew column dependent on conditions.

```
# create data
dat <- data.frame("northcen" = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), "south" = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), "west" = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

# add the new column
dat_new <- dat %>%
  mutate(location = case_when(northcen == 1 ~ "NC",
                              south == 1 ~ "S",
                              west == 1 ~ "W",
                              TRUE ~ "E"))
```

Does this answer your question?